# Solana Metaplex fixed-price-listing

Tags: metaplex, nft

I was working through some tutorials on Metaplex and wanting to leverage the metaplex-program-library instead of using Serum for our secondary marketplace infrastructure.

Initially, I only want to start with fixed-price sales and it looks like the auction house cli has been deprecated. Still trying to figure out the architecture of the entire thing and wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.

The assumption is that we already have let's say 1000 nfts minted via sugar and candy machine. Now I want to build a very simple ui to allow the users that minted to trade with only fixed price mechanics.

Would I need to leverage the auction house and the fixed price program?

Comment: You’ll get a quality answer more quickly if you ask a more specific question. Try to narrow the focus of this one.